# Link method argument to a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, methods, arguments

I have a program where a user is able to receive popular "vacation spots". Al they have to do is enter the continent (Which will bring them to that dictionary) and then enter a country/state (which is a key in a hash) and then it will find the corresponding value.

I have a required file (dict.rb) which is basically a hash module using arrays.

But the issue I have is fairly small. I assigned the user input to two variables, `continent_select` and `country_select`

Here's the code:

```
require './dict.rb'

#create a new dictionary called northamerica
northamerica = Dict.new
Dict.set(northamerica, "new york", "New York City")
Dict.set(northamerica, "new jersey", "Belmar")

puts "Welcome to The Vacation Hub"
puts "What continent are you interested in?"
print '> '

continent_select = $stdin.gets.chomp.downcase 
continent_select.gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '')

puts "Which state would you like to go to in #{continent_select}"
print '> '

country_select = $stdin.gets.chomp.downcase

#puts "You should go to #{Dict.get(northamerica, "#{country_select}")}"
#=> You should go to Belmar

puts "You should go to #{Dict.get(continent_select, "#{country_select}")}"
#=> error
```

Ignore the get and set methods, they're in the included dict.rb

Anyway look carefully at the last few lines. The `Dict.get` method has two arguments. The first finds which dictionary to use. If I just put northamerica as an argument it works. But if I put `continent_select` instead (assuming the user enters 'northamerica') it doesn't work. I think the program is looking for a **Dictionary** named `continent_select`, rather than looking for the **variable** `continent_select`.

**UPDATE**

Here's the whole dict.rb for those who asked.

```
module Dict
    #creates a new dictionary for the user
    def Dict.new(num_buckets=256)
        #initializes a Dict with given num of buckets
        #creates aDict variable which is an empty array
        #that will hold our values later
        aDict = []

        #loop through 0 to the number of buckets
        (0...num_buckets).each do |i|
            #keeps adding arrays to aDict using push method
            aDict.push([])
        end

        return aDict
        #returns [[],[],[]] => array of empty arrays reading to go.
    end

    def Dict.hash_key(aDict, key)
        # Given a key this will create a number and then convert
        # it to an index for the aDict's buckets.
        return key.hash % aDict.length
        #key.hash makes the key a number
        # % aDict.length makes the number between 1 and 256
    end
    def Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)
        #given a key, find where the bucket would go
        #sets the key to a number and it's put in bucket_id variable
        bucket_id = Dict.hash_key(aDict, key)
        #finds the key number in the dict, and returns the key
        return aDict[bucket_id]
    end
    def Dict.get_slot(aDict, key, default=nil)
        #returns the index, key, and value of a slot found in a bucket
        #assigns the key name to the bucket variable
        bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)

        bucket.each_with_index do |kv, i|
            k, v = kv
            if key == k
                return i, k, v
                #returns index key was found in, key, and value
            end
        end

        return -1, key, default
    end
    def Dict.get(aDict, key, default=nil)
        #Gets the value in a bucket for the given key, or the default
        i, k, v = Dict.get_slot(aDict, key, default=default)
        return v
    end
    def Dict.set(aDict, key, value)
        #sets the key to the value, replacing any existing value
        bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)
        i, k, v = Dict.get_slot(aDict, key)

        if i >= 0
            bucket[i] = [key, value]
        else
            bucket.push([key, value])
        end
    end
    def Dict.delete(aDict, key)
        #deletes. the given key from the Dict
        bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)

        (0...bucket.length).each do |i|
            k, v = bucket[i]
            if key == k
                bucket.delete_at(i)
                break
            end
        end
    end
    def Dict.list(aDict)
        #prints out what's in the dict
        aDict.each do |bucket|
            if bucket
                bucket.each {|k, v| puts k, v}
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: If you expect a definitive answer, it would be a good idea to post your implementation of dict.rb so we don't have to guess at what's going on.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Edited post and added dict.rb

Answer (score 1):

Now there's some weird stuff going on.

In the first case, which seems to be okay, you pass the correct arguments:

```
Dict.get(northamerica, "#{country_select}")
```

That is: `Dict` instance as the first argument, and a `String` as the second. But then in the second case:

```
Dict.get(continent_select, "#{country_select}")
```

You pass a `String` instance instead of an obviously expected `Dict`, and this results in an error.

As far as I understand your intention, you want user input to become a variable name to be used as the first argument, but there is no way way it is magically  happening, and you end you up passing just a string.

What you need to do is explicitly map a user input to a corresponding `Dict` object, and then use it. It can look like this:

```
# fetch a Dict object that corresponds to "northamerica" string from a hash
# NOTE: it will raise an exception if a user enters something that's not present
#       in a hash, i.e. something other than "northamerica"
selected_continent_dict = { "northamerica" => northamerica }.fetch(continent_select)
puts "You should go to #{Dict.get(selected_continent_dict, country_select)}"
```

If you're prohibited to use Ruby hashes, you can easily get away with a case statement:

```
selected_continent_dict = case continent_select
  when "northamerica"
    northamerica
  else
    raise "Invalid continent"
  end
puts "You should go to #{Dict.get(selected_continent_dict, country_select)}"
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. Two more advice, if you don't mind:

1. There's no real need for string interpolation in the second argument, and something like `Dict.get(northamerica, country_select)` could be a cleaner way.
2. Better variable naming could save you from headaches. I.e. if you renamed a (quite misleading) `country_select` to a `user_state_selection_string` it would remind you that it is a string, and of what it holds. The example is arbitrary though. There's a wonderful book called "Code Complete" by Steve McConnell which covers this and other issues much better than I do.